# What’s the difference between 'recientemente' and 'últimamente'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, adverbios, diferencias-entre-palabras

What’s the difference between recientemente and últimamente? Both mean 'recent', but when would you use one over another?

Please give reference to the below examples:

> ¿Cómo ha estado el clima recientemente? <sub>What's has been the weather lately?</sub>
>
> ¿Ha escuchado algún buen podcast últimamente? <sub>Have you heard any good podcasts lately?</sub>

Are the words interchangeable?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are pretty much interchangeable (most of the time) to mean the same thing (just as the word ***recently*** is a close synonym of ***lately***, see [source](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define%3A+recently)).

> [recientemente](https://dle.rae.es/?formList=form&w=recientemente#)
>
> 1. adv. Poco tiempo antes. [not long ago]

whereas

> [últimamente](https://dle.rae.es/%C3%BAltimamente)
>
> 1. adv. por último.
> 2. adv. Hace poco tiempo, recientemente.

In these phrases, a simple substitution is okay:

> *He estado recibiendo información en ese sentido **ultimamente** / **recientemente*** 
> [ I have been receiving information in that regard ***lately*** / ***recently*** ]

---

Also both your examples are fine when applying that substitution:

> ¿Cómo ha estado el clima recientemente (/ últimamente)? <sub>What has been the weather lately?</sub>
>
> ¿Ha escuchado algún buen podcast últimamente (/ recientmente)? <sub>Have you heard any good podcasts lately?</sub>

Though there's a nuance when it comes to a singular event. For example

> Choqué mi coche recientemente <sub>I crashed my car recently</sub>

In either language, referring to a single event —not a recurring one— will need **recently** rather than **lately** which would not be correct.

Comment: I cannot say that it is not correct that "In any phrase you could replace one word with the other". However, I would not replace "recientemente" with "últimamente" in some sentences. Mostly when refering to some events of short duration, for example:
'Choqué mi auto últimamente' sounds weird to me, but 'Recientemente choqué mi auto' is ok. Does it depend on the country?

Comment: True, they seem to be have the nuance to that also in Spanish, I updated the response. Many thanks!

Comment: I'd also add that *recientemente* sounds a bit formal. In places where one cannot use *últimamente* I'd just replace it with *hace poco*.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "últimamente" implies some comparison with the previous period, whereas "recientemente" just gives us a time reference, which is *recent*.  Also, "últimamente" could be a shorter interval than "recientemente."  Examples:

- Últimamente no se ve muy contenta mi hermana. [The implication is that previously she seemed a perkier.]
- Ha habido mucha lluvia recientemente. [This doesn't mean necessarily that there was significantly less rain earlier.  The sentence just means that recently there was a lot.]

In your examples, I think that *últimamente* would likely be taken to cover a shorter term than *recientemente*.

Also, as [Pablo said in a comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32291/what-s-the-difference-between-recientemente-and-%C3%BAltimamente/32296#comment57928_32292), "recientemente" can come across as rather formal.  However, the adjective "reciente" has less of a formal feel to it, for example:

- ¿Es un cambio muy reciente?

---

user2325442 came up with a great example (I was in a car accident/*Choqué mi coche*).  This shows that **"últimamente" *only* works for ongoing actions, whereas "recientemente" can in principle work for ongoing or single point in time actions.**

Bottom line, for a conversational tone, the following are recommended:

- **hace poco** for a single point of time action
- **últimamente** for an ongoing action

Comment: I had never heard about 'perkier', what does it mean? It seems to be a funny word

Comment: @fedorqui - It's a fun one.  "Perky" is a bit like "alegre."  Es con el alma ligero.

Comment: @fedorqui there is also the useful intransitive verbal form "to perk up" meaning to cheer up.

Comment: @mdewey oh, cool! Now I remember seeing _perks_ as a section in job offers, with random items such as food, drinks and other things companies offer for free to employees. _Nunca te acostarás sin saber una cosa más_, thanks!

Comment: @mdewey and fedorqui - yes *perks* is another fun one.  But I'm not sure that "perks of the job" necessarily make someone who has been down in the dumps feel noticeably perkier. Fedorqui - here's a typical scenario: someone is in the hospital recovering from an operation.  The first two days are rough.  On the third day, you go to visit again, and you say, "You look perkier than you did yesterday!  I'm glad to see you ate some breakfast!"

Comment: I think we are getting wildly off-topic @fedorqui  here but a perk of the job has a different etymology being an abbreviation for perquisite

Comment: @mdewey - That is interesting and confirms my intuition.  Yes, it is tangential but thanks all the same.

Comment: @fedorqui - Te pingueo para ponerte al tanto de lo que señaló mdewey. (¿*Pinguear* es palabra?)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks @mdewey again and aparente for the _pingueo_. Since I cannot do anything other than thanking you for these infos in English, let me say in Spanish _bendito off-topic_! I learnt a lot today

Comment: @fedorqui - It's a perk (=side benefit) of participation in a language site -- sometimes one learns something about another language.